# Stop overlapping Android Audio Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, notification-channel

When using FCM Notification Channels - it is no longer possible to change the Notification Sound when a notification arrives (using SetSound()). This is causing me a problem when my app receives a notification while the audio of a previous notification is playing. Our notification sound bites are 2-3 seconds long each, and when the second notification arrives, it cuts the first notification's audio off.

Instead of delaying the second notification from displaying, I would like for the second notification to display, but not play any audio. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have that level of control over how Android displays/plays incoming notification messages.

The only approach I can think of is taking full control of the display of the messages in your own application code, by using data messages instead of notification messages.

*Reminder: Firebase Cloud Messaging has two message types: notification messages, and data messages. Notifications messages are automatically handled/displayed by the OS when your app is not active, while data messages are always delivered to your application code.*

From within your application code, you can then use the [Android notification API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) to build the exact display of the message that you want, and display it exactly when you want it (within the notification settings of the user of course).